# How to check a Relative Source is available in Project use codebehind - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a string:

```
"/AssemblyName;component/FileName1.xaml"
```

or

```
"/Views/FileName2.xaml"
```

**How can i check string is available in Project in code behind?**

Comment: That depends where you have that string

Comment: if i'm sure that string is exist in my project. HOw can i check it???

Comment: And i use code in Silverlight Client Side and file in Silverlight Project

Comment: Search your project/solution for `"FileName1.xaml"`, you may find in search result

Comment: >.< i mean using code behind and check FileName1.xaml to find my relative source is available or not available in Project

Answer (score 0):

You could use `File.Exists` method to check if file exists in a particular path. For example:

```
if(File.Exists(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase + "/FileName.xaml")
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work! `File.Exist(...)` always **false**

Comment: Is `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` returning the right path where your "FileName.xaml" is present?

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase return **string.empty**. and i replace File.Exits("/MyAssemblyName; component/MyFileName.xaml") return **false**, too.
And i'm sure myFileNAme exist

Comment: It doesn't return empty. Wonder why it is so in your case. Try this instead: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` if you are using WPF

Comment: i'm using Silverlight with WCF RIA Service and not found System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain. **BaseDirectory**. Do you have any idea?